# Preferable pattern for getting around the "moving out of borrowed self" checker

Tags: oop, design-patterns, rust

Consider the pattern where there are several states registered with a dispatcher and each state knows what state to transition to when it receives an appropriate event. This is a simple state transition pattern.

```
struct Dispatcher {
    states: HashMap<Uid, Rc<RefCell<State>>>,
}
impl Dispatcher {
    pub fn insert_state(&mut self, state_id: Uid, state: Rc<RefCell<State>>) -> Option<Rc<RefCell<State>>> {
        self.states.insert(state_id, state)
    }
    fn dispatch(&mut self, state_id: Uid, event: Event) {
        if let Some(mut state) = states.get_mut(&state_id).cloned() {
            state.handle_event(self, event);
        }
    }
}

trait State {
    fn handle_event(&mut self, &mut Dispatcher, Event);
}

struct S0 {
    state_id: Uid,
    move_only_field: Option<MOF>,
    // This is pattern that concerns me.
}
impl State for S0 {
    fn handle_event(&mut self, dispatcher: &mut Dispatcher, event: Event) {
        if event == Event::SomeEvent {
            // Do some work
            if let Some(mof) = self.mof.take() {
                let next_state = Rc::new(RefCell::new(S0 {
                    state_id: self.state_id,
                    move_only_field: mof,
                }));
                let _ = dispatcher.insert(self.state_id, next_state);
            } else {
                // log an error: BUGGY Logic somewhere
                let _ = dispatcher.remove_state(&self.state_id);
            }
        } else {
            // Do some other work, maybe transition to State S2 etc.
        }
    }
}

struct S1 {
    state_id: Uid,
    move_only_field: MOF,
}
impl State for S1 {
    fn handle_event(&mut self, dispatcher: &mut Dispatcher, event: Event) {
        // Do some work, maybe transition to State S2/S3/S4 etc.
    }
}
```

With reference to the inline comment above saying:

```
// This is pattern that concerns me.
```

`S0::move_only_field` needs to be an `Option` in this pattern because `self` is borrowed in `handle_event`, but I am not sure that this is best way to approach it.

Here are the ways I can think of with demerits of each one:

1. Put it into an `Option` as I have done: this feels hacky and every time I need
   to check the invariant that the `Option` is always `Some` otherwise
   `panic!` or make it a NOP with `if let Some() =` and ignore
   the else clause, but this causes code-bloat. Doing an `unwrap`
   or bloating the code with `if let Some()` feels a bit off.
2. Get it into a shared ownership `Rc<RefCell<>>`: Need to heap allocate
   all such variables or construct another struct called `Inner` or
   something that has all these non-clonable types and put that into an
   `Rc<RefCell<>>`.
3. Pass stuff back to `Dispatcher` indicating it to basically remove us
   from the map and then move things out of us to the next `State` which
   will also be indicated via our return value: Too much coupling,
   breaks OOP, does not scale as `Dispatcher` needs to know about all the
   `State`s and needs frequent updating. I don't think this is a good
   paradigm, but could be wrong.
4. Implement `Default` for MOF above: Now we can `mem::replace` it with
   the default while moving out the old value. The burden of panicking OR
   returning an error OR doing a NOP is now hidden in implementation of
   `MOF`. The problem here is we don't always have the access to MOF
   type and for those that we do, it again takes the point of bloat
   from user code to the code of MOF.
5. Let the function `handle_event` take `self` by move as `fn handle_event(mut self, ...) -> Option<Self>`: Now instead of `Rc<RefCell<>>` you will need to have `Box<State>` and move it out each time in the dispatcher and if the return is `Some` you put it back. This almost feels like a sledgehammer and makes many other idioms impossible, for instance if I wanted to share self further in some registered closure/callback I would normally put a `Weak<RefCell<>>` previously but now sharing self in callbacks etc is impossible.

Are there any other options? Is there any that is considered the "***most idiomatic***" way of doing this in Rust?

Comment: What does `Dispatcher` even *do*? The only way I can make sense of this is that you have multiple state machines with different `Uid`s and the dispatcher picks one to handle each event. Why do you keep all the "used" states in the `HashMap` -- will a state ever be re-entered? How?

Comment: All of the pain is because the overall technique is not panic-safe. In-between the time that you've moved out the old state and moved in the new state, the program could panic. If it did, the container of the state would be in an unknown condition, which means that running the destructor could have access to memory it shouldn't; breaking a core component of Rust's safety.

Comment: @trentcl Dispatcher is just the normal event queue mechanism. Consider something like mio tokens. So mio will give you the readiness event (readable, writable etc) and the token for which it was invoked. You map that token (Uid here) to your state implementation. There are no "used" states in HashMap. When the state transitions it removes itself - where do you see that in the code ?

Comment: @Shepmaster I couldn't fully grasp what you meant - what dtor will have access to memory it shouldn't ? Also there is no `unsafe` code here so what safety has been broken ? Also how do you suggest tackling this problem ?

Comment: The destructor of `S0` will call the destructor of `MOF`. If you've moved `MOF` out of `S0` but not yet replaced it, that destructor *would have* access to undefined memory. That's why the compiler disallows it. I'm not saying you *have* unsafety, just explaining why that field always has to be valid otherwise there would be unsafety. There's no universal answer. See [the closed RFC for *lots* of discussion](https://github.com/rust-lang/rfcs/pull/1736)

Comment: @Shepmaster Ah i get you now, thought you were saying the code as it is is unsafe. Ok - i would think this state transition pattern with `Rc<RefCell` is common in single threaded event based mechanisms. So which would be your preferred approach (or if none then what would you replace this way of doing things with).

Comment: You don't have any code that removes the old state on transition; I didn't realize it was supposed to be there.

Comment: @trentcl Ofcourse it does - it's not a multimap - just a normal rust std HashMap. Re-read the insert logic in the code - that's going to displace the previous stuff (that's what inserts normally do). And in case you missed that logic, the else branch also explicitly calls `remove_state` which is assumed to be complementary to `insert_state` which is already coded.

Comment: Of course, I overlooked that you're always re-inserting with the same `state_id`

Answer (score 1):

> 5. Let the function handle_event take self by move as `fn handle_event(mut self, ...) -> Option<Self>`: Now instead of `Rc<RefCell<>>` you will need to have `Box<State>` and move it out each time in the dispatcher and if the return is Some you put it back.

This is what I would do. However, you don't need to switch from `Rc` to `Box` if there is only one strong reference: [`Rc::try_unwrap`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/rc/struct.Rc.html#method.try_unwrap) can move out of an `Rc`.

Here's part of how you might rewrite `Dispatcher`:

```
struct Dispatcher {
    states: HashMap<Uid, Rc<State>>,
}
impl Dispatcher {
    fn dispatch(&mut self, state_id: Uid, event: Event) {
        if let Some(state_ref) = self.states.remove(&state_id) {
            let state = state_ref.try_unwrap()
                .expect("Unique strong reference required");
            if let Some(next_state) = state.handle_event(event) {
                self.states.insert(state_id, next_state);
            }
        } else {
            // handle state_id not found
        }
    }
}
```

(Note: `dispatch` takes `state_id` by value. In the original version, this wasn't necessary -- it could have been changed to pass by reference. In this version, it is necessary, since `state_id` gets passed to `HashMap::insert`. It looks like `Uid` is `Copy` though, so it makes little difference.)

It's not clear whether `state_id` actually needs to be a member of the struct that implements `State` anymore, since you don't need it inside `handle_event` -- all the insertion and removal happens inside `impl Dispatcher`, which makes sense and reduces coupling between `State` and `Dispatcher`.

```
impl State for S0 {
    fn handle_event(self, event: Event) -> Option<Rc<State>> {
        if event == Event::SomeEvent {
            // Do some work
            let next_state = Rc::new(S0 {
                state_id: self.state_id,
                move_only_field: self.mof,
            });
            Some(next_state)
        } else {
            // Do some other work
        }
    }
}
```

Now you don't have to handle a weird, should-be-impossible corner case where the Option is None.

> This almost feels like a sledgehammer and makes many other idioms impossible, for instance if I wanted to share self further in some registered closure/callback I would normally put a `Weak<RefCell<>>` previously but now sharing self in callbacks etc is impossible.

Because you can move out of an `Rc` if you have the only strong reference, you don't have to sacrifice this technique.

"Feels like a sledgehammer" might be subjective, but to me, what a signature like `fn handle_event(mut self, ...) -> Option<Self>` does is encode an invariant. With the original version, each `impl State for ...` had to know when to insert and remove itself from the dispatcher, and whether it did or not was uncheckable. For example, if somewhere deep in the logic you forgot to call `dispatcher.insert(state_id, next_state)`, the state machine wouldn't transition, and might get stuck or worse. When `handle_event` takes `self` by-value, that's not possible anymore -- you *have* to return the next state, or the code simply won't compile.

(Aside: both the original version and mine do at least two hashtable lookups each time `dispatch` is called: once to get the current state, and again to insert the new state. If you wanted to get rid of the second lookup, you could combine approaches: store `Option<Rc<State>>` in the `HashMap`, and `take` from the `Option` instead of removing it from the map entirely.)